# Google Chrome People menu shortcuts stopped working on MAC

Tags: google-chrome, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I previously set MAC shortcuts for my different Google accounts in Chrome.
This worked fine for a few months, and now it suddenly stopped working.
Anyone has idea why?
Thanks.
MAC OS 10.14.6 (18G1012)
Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like chrome has changed my "People" menu naming convention. If I had:

- ORGANIZAITON_1
- ORGANIZAITON_2
- ORGANIZAITON_3

Now I have:

- MY_FIRST_NAME (ORGANIZAITON_1)
- MY_FIRST_NAME (ORGANIZAITON_2)
- MY_FIRST_NAME (ORGANIZAITON_3)

The solution was as follows:
Restart your MAC -> Launch Chrome -> Look at people tab -> Update the old shortcuts to match the exact names appearing in the People menu.